# Why is \$V_{\text{ov}}\$ not a good design parameter?

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, integrated-circuit

Can anyone explain why \$V_{\text{ov}}\$ is not a good design parameter here?
I understand why \$C_{\text{gs}}\$ is bigger (low bandwidth), but still can't understand the conclusion they made.

**Source**: [Design of MOS Amplifiers](https://designers-guide.org/forum/Attachments/Gm_BY_ID_Methodology.pdf)

(page 6/25)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Optimizing design does not include any benefit for choosing Vov first. It is just not an important performance result.

Yet it is chosen after designing for useful FoM's like gm/Id and gm*ro and gm/Cgs.